# Sharepoint Central administrator new website shows 401 unauthorized

Tags: web, sharepoint-2013, unauthorized

I have sharepoint server central administrator installed in my computer, Then I created new web application followed by my new site collection. Now when I accessed the site from outside the intranet using a mapped address, the site gets loaded with my login credentials.I can access homepage of my new site. But I can't traverse to any other features like site content, site settings, etc..It shows 401 UNAUTHORIZED.

I am able to set new links in the homepage and it works fine using  http://ip_address:port/default.aspx

I have tried deactivating Minimal Download Strategy and also I have configured the alternate access mapping, it did'nt workout for me.

Can anyone tell me why I am not able to access pages other than my homepage and also all its features.

Answer (score 0):

I have self-cleared this issue. The problem is that it seems to redirect to /_layout/15/ path automatically. To avoid this it just need to deactivate Minimal Download Strategy in Site Settings > Manage Site Features. But please make sure that you are doing this for your new site, also it needs to be done from a machine in sharepoint server private network. Hope you got it..